# Jquery Cookie remember class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have the following code, and want to adjust it to remember the class added in order for it apply throughout the site. I have come across Jquery Cookie:https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie and looking to use this to remember the applied class. How do I save the current state?

```
    $.cookie('elemshow.on');    
var elemhide = $('.hide-menu'),
    elemshow = $('.show-menu, .show-menu2');

    elemhide.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('header').addClass('out-active');
        $('.header-foot').addClass('out-active');
        $('#content').addClass('full-width-added');
        setTimeout(function() {
            try {
                reconstructRn();
            } catch(err) {
            }
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
            elemshow.addClass('active');
        }, 300);

    });

    elemshow.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('header').removeClass('out-active');
        $('.header-foot').removeClass('out-active');
        $('#content').removeClass('full-width-added');
        elemshow.removeClass('active');
        setTimeout(function() {
            try {
                reconstructRevolution();
            } catch(err) {

            }
        }, 10);

    });
```

Comment: Do you have HTML to go with your code? Which element(s) are you changing classes on and how are you changing from one class to the other? Some background info goes a long way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would adjust your code like this:

```
/* define elemhide and elemshow */
var elemhide = $('.hide-menu'),
    elemshow = $('.show-menu, .show-menu2');

/* click functions */
elemhide.on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    /* cookie = 1 week */
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
    $.cookie('menu_cookie', '0', { expires: date, path: '/' });

    /* set classes */
    $('header').addClass('out-active');
    $('.header-foot').addClass('out-active');
    $('#content').addClass('full-width-added');
    setTimeout(function() {
        try {
            reconstructRn();
        } catch(err) {
            // do something
        }
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        elemshow.addClass('active');
    }, 300);

});

elemshow.on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    /* cookie = 1 week */
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
    $.cookie('menu_cookie', '1', { expires: date, path: '/' });

    /* set classes */
    $('header').removeClass('out-active');
    $('.header-foot').removeClass('out-active');
    $('#content').removeClass('full-width-added');
    elemshow.removeClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
        try {
            reconstructRevolution();
        } catch(err) {
            // do something
        }
    }, 10);

});

/* check for existing cookie */
if (!$.cookie('menu_cookie') || $.cookie('menu_cookie') == 0) {
    $('.hide-menu').trigger('click');
} else if ($.cookie('menu_cookie') == 1) {
    $('.show-menu').trigger('click');
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/B8XBg/ I didn't know your HTML so I just worked with colors...